# What are the origins of the Xenomorph?

Tags: alien-franchise, xenomorph

I have seen several of the Alien movies and Prometheus but in none of them do they ever mention anything of the alien's home planet. Recently a friend claimed that they came from a far away planet where they were the bottom of the food chain and fled to survive. Is this true? If not where did they come from?

Comment: Having spent a bit of time searching, I don't believe there are any official source for the [alien homeworld.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21182/how-does-the-xenomorph-evolution-timeline-work-in-the-alien-predator-universe/21190#21190)

Comment: From the commentary on Alien, the xenomorph are bio-engineered, and thus have no home planet.

Comment: I think sequel of prometheus will explain this

Comment: Didn't Prometheus explain that they were engineered?

Comment: I'd hate to see the planet where xenomorphs are the bottom of the food chain!

Comment: Prometheus didn't really explain anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Prometheus, the crew posit that the Engineers created the black goo that (at the end of the film) gave rise to a Xenomorph.

As the Xenomorph's are bio-engineered they have no home world, though the black goo that they eventually evolved from was probably originally created on the planet in Prometheus (certainly much of the research/experimentation appeared to be done there, probably safely away from the Engineer's home world) then that planet (LV-223) could be considered to be their home world in the sense of "their planet of origin".

Comment: I believe nothing gets really explained in _Prometheus_. What the Engineers wanted to do with the black goo, whether the xenomorph was a intentional byproduct, whether the black goo is a bioweapon, whether the black goo was actually engineered by the Engineers. For all we know the black goo is a naturally occurring substance. The human crew speculates a lot, but they don't come to any actual conclusions, do they?

Comment: There is a Xenomorph homeworld: Xenomorph Prime