# Has there been a story of Predators mutated by and into Aliens?

Tags: aliens, alien-vs.-predator

In Prometheus, the Engineer was forcefully impregnated by the mutated octopus-like love child of Elizabeth Shaw. After its progeny burst from the Engineer's chest, it resulted in the original Alien creature that first appeared with Ripley.

Now since there is Aliens vs. Predators which never has been taken seriously compared with the original story line in my opinion, but I have to know, has there been a case where a similar mutation occurred with Predators?

That would have to be a very bad-ass combo although I have to lower myself in IQ by asking that.

Comment: "it resulted in the original Alien creature that first appeared with Ripley" - maybe. I thought it looked a little bit different. Presumably it was the creature that laid the eggs that produced the face-hugger that impregnated Kane, from whom the alien emerged that Ripley eventually killed.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, it's not the same creature. A- it looks different to the creature from _Alien_. B- the spaceship is not the derelict from _Alien_ or _Aliens_ (it's not located in planet LV-426). C- it can't be the same creature, since the Space Jockey didn't die fused to its chair, as found in the derelict by the characters from _Alien_. So no, different alien, different Jockey and different planet!

Comment: @AndresF.: ah, gotcha. I totally did not grok that from the movie.

Comment: “there is Aliens vs. Predators which never has been taken seriously compared with the original story line in my opinion” — and, apparently, [Ridley Scott’s opinion too](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/4392/6107).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Aliens vs Predator: Requiem* showed us what a Xenomorph would look like after gestating inside of a Predator:

[image: "Predalien" from AvP:R, showing Yautja dreadlocks/quills, much lighter body pigmentation on the underside of the body (similar to predators), as well as predator-like mandibles.]

[more images](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=avp%20requiem%20predalien&hl=en&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ggj1UJu5GMKhigeK-IFY&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAA&biw=1920&bih=1063)

Comment: It'd be nice if people would actually take the time to enter an image description since SE actually gives you that ability.

Comment: I never knew of this ability until you just mentioned it, and I don't ever remember being prompted for a description before trying today

Comment: I don't think it prompts you. It just adds the markdown with the placeholder text for the image description in the generated code. Perhaps more people would add a descriptive alt text if the image insertion feature actually prompts you for one explicitly.

Comment: That's what I mean - I don't think I ever remember the image insertion doing that before

Answer (score 2):

No fully developed Predator/Alien hybrid has ever been seen in cinema but at the end of [Aliens vs Predator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_%28film%29), we see the dead body of the Predator on their ship sprout the head of a hybrid as the movie ends.

[image: The infant "Predalien" — like a regular alien chest-burster, but with adorable itty-bitty Predator-style mandibles]

*The "Predalien" from Aliens vs. Predator*

- Also see: [How do solitary aliens reproduce in the Aliens franchise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12424/how-did-solitary-aliens-reproduce-in-the-alien-franchise)
- Also see: [What purpose does acidic blood serve to an alien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/what-purpose-does-acidic-blood-serve-to-a-xenomorph/13678#13678)

Comment: So this also infers that when the face hugger "impregnates" the host, it actually works similarly in a twisted fashion of sexual reproduction as its progeny has DNA from both the host and the Alien mother. That Giger is a sick bastard if I may say so as it combines too many horrific concepts.

Comment: A fully developed Predalien _has_ been shown in cinema. See HorusKol's answer.

Comment: @zipstory.com: I’m not sure whether that aspect of the alien was designed by Giger. I think he mainly did the visual aspects. The idea that Aliens would resemble the creatures they gestated in wasn’t established until Alien 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Alien vs Predator 2 theres an abomination, basically crossover between an alien and a predator. mutation. but no fully developed